# Access internet when connected to VPN

Tags: ubuntu, iproute, pptp

I am connected to a VPN network through a pptp connection. The target network does not provide Internet access, thus I can't connect to it.
How should I route my Internet traffic through my existing connection?

Below, are my existing routes

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref   Use Iface
default         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     50     0        0 ppp0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlp4s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0
_gateway        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wlp4s0
192.168.116.42  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 ppp0
212.80.25.88    _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp4s0
212.80.25.88    _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp4s0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to setup a default route.  I do this:

```
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 metric 40
```

where:

```
192.168.1.1 = local gateway (not VPN gateway)
metric 40 = Some metric that is lower than your existing default route
```

---

In simple steps:

1. Without being on VPN use `ip route` and note the line beginning with default (`proto`, `dhcp` aren't important)
2. Connect to VPN
3. Use `ip route add`, then append the line you noted before, but make the metric lower than anything that may currently exist.

---

With this setup, I can access all *intra*net tools that would normally be available via a VPN, while diverting all *inter*net traffic away from it.

---

Edit: I saw your updated routing table. `192.168.1.1` is probably the route you want, and `metric 40` will work because it's lower than the default VPN route which is `50`.

Comment: that metric does the trick.

Comment: Oops, I changed the routing and I have an access to internet. However, vpn network becomes inaccessible.

Comment: Do you know the IP range of your VPN stuff?  Let's say it's 10.10.x.x.  You could add a route with:  `sudo ip route add 10.10.0.0/16 via dev ppp0`.  Then anything within that IP range will be sent via your VPN.

Comment: You can always `ip route del X` where `X` is the route printed when you type `ip route`

Comment: your suggestion does the trick, but I made it in this way: sudo ip route add 10.10.0.0/16  dev ppp0

Answer (score 2):

Your VPN connection is overriding your default route (`0.0.0.0/0`), and most likely your DNS resolvers. You could suppress or override both those things and just have specific routes to the ranges you're interested in on the target network.

Comment: I have updated my question, would you please provide a more explicit solution?